# chaining multiples context providers working on the same realm in react native

Tags: react-native, realm, use-effect, react-context

I'm trying to chain multiple ContextProviders divided by distinct purposes to work on the same realm in react native.

```
<FirstRealmProvider>
   <SecondRealmProvider>
     <FunctionalComonentUsingHooksFromFristAndSecond>
   </SecondRealmProvider> 
</FirstRealmProvider>
```

I'm initialising (opening) the realm in the first component (it's also responsible for closing etc.) and save the ref to it via `realmRef = useRef<Realm>(null);` with the help of a useEffect hook. Using exported context functions and collections from the first component within the second and the third one seams to work fine unless I implement another useEffect in the *SecondRealmProvider* (with or without accessing the realm directly or its exported ref).
If I do that realm complains about `realmRef.current` being null (which is set in the useEffect of *FirstRealmProvider* and should not be null unless the useEffect get called after the inner useEffect of *SecondRealmProvider* has been called first. In this case it seams not to be possible to chain and share the logic by concerns and the *FirstRealmProvider* would become a multipurpose over cluttered component.

Please help me to pinpoint what am I missing here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since react initialises (calls useEffect) first on the inner components those can not use functionality from the outer ones if this relies on initialisation as well. To make it work anyway I added a is"Particular"ProviderInitialized like this:

```
const [nlpIsInitialized, setInitialized] = useState<boolean>(false);
```

and each provider ignores useEffect until the outer provider reported to be initialised as well. The useEffect also depends on the initialised value of the outer Provider, and everything works now like it should.